# WTForms validation does not work (Flask+mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, flask, wtforms

I have a simple web page to retrieve and edit json data from mongo.
Adding articles to mongo works fine as well as validation.
Validation for the name field is set to be between 4 and 20, for upc between 4 and 12.
But when I try to get the same previously created article(item) using Edit block and if I want to change something, it will just save it without any validation as is (even, if I input 15 digits for upc), then if I open the same file for the second time, make some changes again and try to save it, validation fails. It just keeps throwing an error like "Field must be between 4 and 20 characters long" even if it is already within the limits. I suspect this is something related to rendering these field from json file to the view, but I am not sure. I already tried to implement  csrf protection, but it didnt help.

So here is the app.py

```
class ArticleForm(Form):
class Meta:
    csrf = True
    csrf_class = SessionCSRF
    csrf_secret = b'EPj00jpfj8Gx1SjnyLxwBBSQfnQ9DJYe0Ym'

    @property
    def csrf_context(self):
        return session

name = StringField('Name', [validators.length(min=4, max=200)])
upc = StringField('UPC', [validators.length(min=4, max=12)])


#Edit Item
@app.route('/edit_item/<string:id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
@is_logged_in
def edit_item(id):
coll = mongo.db.items
item = coll.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)})

form = ArticleForm(request.form)

form.name.data = item['name']
form.upc.data = item['upc']

if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    name = request.form['name']
    upc = request.form['upc']
    author = session['username']

#Update fields in database
    coll.update({'_id':ObjectId(id)}, {'$set': {'name': name, 'upc': upc}})

    flash('You have successfully added the item!', 'success')

    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
return render_template('edit_item.html', form=form)
```

This is render_field block:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  {{ field.label }}
  {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <span class="help-inline">{{ error }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

And View:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
  <h1>Edit Item</h1>
  {% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
  <form method="POST" action="">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.name, class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.upc, class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```